# Deselect an index of TreeView from QML

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I would like to deselect an index in a Treeview programmatically and from QML. I have a function that accepts the QModelIndex of the tree node that needs to be deselected and I do the following:

```
function deselectNode(index)
{
 myTreeView.selection.select(index, ItemSelectionModel.Deselect)
}
```

I expect this function to trigger the selectionChanged event on the tree and deselect that index, but it does nothing. I also tried with Toggle. Is there another way to deselect just one single node from tree?

In other words, I want to do what Cmd/Ctrl + Click on a tree node does, but in Qml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was that I was setting the currentIndex of my tree also in another place. So the function I mentioned in my question actually works fine and can deselect a node from the tree programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Ctrl + Click behavior on a tree node, set [`selectionMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#selectionMode-prop) to `SelectionMode.MultiSelection` or `SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection`, you don't need to write your own deselect function.

But sometimes `function deselectNode` is still required when some events outside the `TreeView` are triggered. To implement `deselectNode`, it depends on current `selectionMode` of the `TreeView`:

- **SelectionMode.NoSelection**: nothing can be selected and `deselectNode` is not necessary.
- **SelectionMode.SingleSelection**: use `myTreeView.selection.clearCurrentIndex()` to clear current selection.
- **SelectionMode.MultiSelection**, **SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection**, and **SelectionMode.ContiguousSelection**: `myTreeView.selection.select(index, ItemSelectionModel.Deselect)` works as expected.